# Unable to integrate IE9 rendering engine with vb.net Browser control

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry, browser, internet-explorer-9

I tried this registry below and it didn't work. My application name is 'Testapp', using VS2010 on windows 7 with IE9 installed. I want to render the pages in IE9 not IE7.

Link below helped me out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation

used this registry below, by making one separately then registered in registry. After that I launched my app but it still loaded in IE7.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
> "testapp.exe"=dword:00002328

Can anyone help me out that how can I use IE9 as render instead of IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be dword:000090000 not dword:00002328

Comment: just tried and it's not working. Apparently, everyone is stating the same way on the internet forums but I don't see it working for me.